# ZooKeeper 3.4.12 C client fails to connect to ZooKeeper server on Solaris11 machine

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper, solaris

I compiled the ZooKeeper 3.4.12 C client on Solaris 11 machine and trying to test it through cli.sh. Here is the sample code that I changed in cli.c. Whenever I run the ./cli_mt file it always throws below error

> 2018-08-08 09:49:44,437:18000(0x2):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1670: Socket [10.272.80.184:4831] zk retcode=-4, errno=0(Error 0): connect() call failed.

Anybody facing same issue?.

---

### cli.c file

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
#ifndef THREADED
    fd_set rfds, wfds, efds;
    int processed = 0;
#endif
    char p[2048];
#ifdef YCA  
    char *cert = 0;
    char appId[64];
#endif
    char buffer[4096];
    int bufoff;
    struct Stat stat;
    int buflen = sizeof(buffer);
    int rc;
    verbose = 0;

    zoo_set_debug_level(ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_WARN);
    zoo_deterministic_conn_order(1); // enable deterministic order
    hostPort = argv[1];
    printf("\n%s\n", "Lets connect");
    zh = zookeeper_init("sld06hzt:4831", watcher, 30000, &myid, 0, 0);
    if (!zh) {
        printf("\n%d\n", errno);
        return errno;
    }
    strcpy(p,"sadmin:ldap");
    zoo_add_auth(zh, "digest", p,strlen(p), 0, 0);
    rc = zoo_get(zh, "/test", 0, buffer, &buflen, &stat);
    if (rc) {
        printf("\n%s\n", buffer);
    }
    zookeeper_close(zh);
    return 2;
}
```

Regards,
Ashwini.

Comment: Try running your process under [the `truss` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/truss-1.html) to see what calls it's actually making.  If you can get the arguments actually passed to `connect()` you may be able to find what's going wrong.  Something like `truss -f -a -vall -o /path/to/output/file ./cli_mt` will trace all calls your program makes into the kernel, including the `connect` call.